# Prolog: Optimizing a puzzle solver

Tags: optimization, prolog, clpfd

I am currently solving a specific kenken problem, and I notice it takes about 5 seconds to solve. This is for a smaller puzzle. However, I also need to solve a larger one, and I am concerned that the solution will take far too long to find. Here is the most relevant parts of my code (I have removed redundant parts, they are of the expected form):

```
getlarger(First, Second, First) :- First >= Second.
getlarger(First, Second, Second) :- First < Second.

getsmaller(First, Second, Second) :- First >= Second.
getsmaller(First, Second, First) :- First < Second.

subtractsmallerfromlarger(First, Second, Result) :- getlarger(First, Second, Larger), 
    getsmaller(First, Second, Smaller), Result is Larger - Smaller.

intdividelargerbysmaller(First, Second, Result) :- getlarger(First, Second, Larger),
getsmaller(First, Second, Smaller), Result is Larger // Smaller.

groupof4(List) :- nodups(List).

allrowsof4([X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9, X10, X11, X12, X13, X14, X15, X16]) :-
    groupof4([X1, X5, X9, X13]), groupof4([X2, X6, X10, X14]), %snip....

allcolumnsof4([X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9, X10, X11, X12, X13, X14, X15, X16]) :-
    groupof4([X1, X2, X3, X4]), groupof4([X5, X6, X7, X8]), %snip....

validnumbers4([X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9, X10, X11, X12, X13, X14, X15, X16]) :-
    validnumber4(X1), validnumber4(X2), %.....

kenken([X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9, X10, X11, X12, X13, X14, X15, X16]) :-
    %snip...
    validnumbers4([X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9, X10, X11, X12, X13, X14, X15, X16]),
    X5 * X1 * X2 =:= 2,
    %Additional Arithmetic contraints removed
    intdividelargerbysmaller(X11, X15, 2), %Dividend =:= 2,
    subtractsmallerfromlarger(X12, X16, 3), %Difference =:= 3,
    X13 * X14 =:= 6,
    allcolumnsof4([X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9, X10, X11, X12, X13, X14, X15, X16]),
    allrowsof4([X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9, X10, X11, X12, X13, X14, X15, X16]).
```

For the already defined values, I use the syntax: `X1 is 5`, and I put this at the top of my code thinking that it would speed up lookup.

Without having to make my code drastically complex, are there any spots where I can make it somewhat more efficient?

Also, I noticed that changing the intdividelargerbysmaller and subtractsmallerfromlarger "Result is" to "Result =" makes the query take a very long time / not solve, whereas if I use a variable in the third slot it solves with both.

Additionally I noticed that queries take a very long time if I move the row and column checking up to near the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be using a *generate-then-test* approach, which first generates candidates and then checks whether they are valid solutions.

It is much more efficient to use *constraints* for this task. Consider using *finite domain constraints*, which are provided by `library(clpfd)` in SWI-Prolog.

Constraints allow you to declaratively state all requirements even before you search for concrete solutions. They can filter inconsistent elements before and during the search, which typically yields tremendous performance improvements.

Comment: Thanks, I had some trouble getting the library to work, but I figured out how to get it installed. Would you care to give me some pointers on how to use the constraints?

Comment: Simply use the finite domain constraints like `#=/2`, `#>=/2` etc. as drop-in replacements for the corresponding lower-level arithmetic predicates (`is/2`, `>/2` etc.). Constrain the domains of all variables, then use `labeling/2` or `label/1` to search for concrete solutions.

Comment: Not sure how to use labels, but I am seeing massive performance improvements. However, my two functions to subtract the lesser from the greater and the similar division function don't work now. I'll try to troubleshoot it.

Comment: To subtract the lesser from the greater you can use the finite domain constraint `S #= max(X,Y) - min(X,Y)`. Also, `label/1` is easy to use: `label(Vars)`, where `Vars` are the finite domain variables you want to label.

Comment: I don't seem to need labels, but it's working really well now. Really fast. Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisChambers: Read [the manual with small examples](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html) and then [search for uses](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[clpfd]+label+labeling).